# Сделать блок кликабельным через сss

Tags: php, css

Есть код при наведении на объект появляется поле. Как сделать так что бы поле появлялось при клике и не исчезало пока не кликнешь второй раз.

```
<tbody>
    <?php 
        $fday=$params->get('firstday');
        for($i = 0; $i < count($cal->weeks); $i++)
        { 
        ?><tr class="week<?php echo $i+1; ?>">
            <?php
            for($j=0; $j < 7; $j++) 
            {
                if(!empty($cal->weeks[$i][$j])) 
                {
                    $day = explode(' ',$cal->weeks[$i][$j]);
                    $class = 'nc-day';  
                    $ul = '';               
                    if ( $day[1] ) { 
                        $class .= " outofmonth";
                    } else {
                        $class .= " weekday".((($j+$fday)>6)?(($j+$fday)-6):($j+$fday+1)) . " relday" . ($j+1); 
                        if ($day[0]==date('j') && $cal->curmonth==date('m')) {
                            $class .= " today"; 
                        }
                    }
                    if (isset($cal->items[$day[0]]) && !$day[1]) {
                        $class .= " hasitems";  
                    }
                    ?><td><span class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php 
                        echo $day[0];
                        if (isset($cal->items[$day[0]]) && !$day[1]) { ?>

                        <ul class="nc-items"><?php

                        foreach ($cal->items[$day[0]] as $item) { ?> 
                            <li><a href="<?php echo preg_replace('/modules\/mod_newscalendar\/assets\//', '', $item->link); ?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $item->title; ?></a></li><?php }
                        ?></ul>
                    <?php } 
                   ?></span></td>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <td></td><?php
                }
            } ?>
            </tr>
    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
```

Блок который появляется при наведении на объект:

```
<ul class="nc-items"><?php

                        foreach ($cal->items[$day[0]] as $item) { ?> 
                            <li><a href="<?php echo preg_replace('/modules\/mod_newscalendar\/assets\//', '', $item->link); ?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $item->title; ?></a></li><?php }
                        ?></ul>
```

Объект на который надо кликать:

```
<td><span class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php 
                        echo $day[0];
                        if (isset($cal->items[$day[0]]) && !$day[1]) { ?>

                        <ul class="nc-items"><?php

                        foreach ($cal->items[$day[0]] as $item) { ?> 
                            <li><a href="<?php echo preg_replace('/modules\/mod_newscalendar\/assets\//', '', $item->link); ?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $item->title; ?></a></li><?php }
                        ?></ul>
                    <?php } 
                   ?></span></td>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS

```css
.test {
    position: relative;
}
.test:focus .test-inner {
    display: block;
}

.test-inner {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<tbody>
  <?php 
            $fday=$params->get('firstday');
            for($i = 0; $i < count($cal->weeks); $i++)
            { 
            ?><tr class="week<?php echo $i+1; ?>">
    <?php
                for($j=0; $j < 7; $j++) 
                {
                    if(!empty($cal->weeks[$i][$j])) 
                    {
                        $day = explode(' ',$cal->weeks[$i][$j]);
                        $class = 'nc-day'; 
                        $ul = '';    
                        if ( $day[1] ) { 
                            $class .= " outofmonth";
                        } else {
                            $class .= " weekday".((($j+$fday)>6)?(($j+$fday)-6):($j+$fday+1)) . " relday" . ($j+1); 
                            if ($day[0]==date('j') && $cal->curmonth==date('m')) {
                                $class .= " today"; 
                            }
                        }
                        if (isset($cal->items[$day[0]]) && !$day[1]) {
                            $class .= " hasitems"; 
                        }
                        ?><td class="test" tabindex="-1"><span class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php 
       echo $day[0];
                         if (isset($cal->items[$day[0]]) && !$day[1]) { ?>
                            
                            <ul class="nc-items test-inner"><?php
       
                            foreach ($cal->items[$day[0]] as $item) { ?> 
                                <li><a href="<?php echo preg_replace('/modules\/mod_newscalendar\/assets\//', '', $item->link); ?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $item->title; ?></a></li><?php }
                            ?></ul>
                        <?php } 
                       ?></span></td>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <td></td><?php
                    }
                } ?>
                </tr>
  <?php } ?>
            
        </tbody>
```